# Does $\pi$ consist of $\pi$ in it?

Tags: proof-verification

We do not know whether $\pi$ consists every real number in its decimals, or not. However, If we assume that $\pi$ is consisted in $\pi$ then (I think) we reach a contradiction.

$\pi=\underbrace{3.14159265359...}_{n\; terms}\underbrace{314159265359...}_{\pi's\; decimals}$

Then we have:

$\pi 10^{n-1}=\underbrace{314159265359.....}_{an\;integer}\underbrace{.}_{dot}314159265359....$

> $\lfloor x\rfloor$ :  greater integer function

so

$$\pi 10^{n-1}=\lfloor\pi10^{n-1}\rfloor+\dfrac{\pi}{10}\\ \Rightarrow \pi\underbrace{(10^n-1)}_{\in \mathbb Z}=\underbrace{10\lfloor\pi10^{n-1}\rfloor}_{\in \mathbb Z}$$

However, it is contradiction.

***Result:*** If the calculation is true, then can we exactly say that $\pi$ does not consist every number?
Or can we just say that $\pi$ doesnot consist of $\pi$?

***Edit:***

In comment section, as @fleablood has mentioned, I wanted to draw attention to what if $\pi$ has interesting irrationals in it (I mean at its tail), how can we verify.

Comment: $\pi$ has infinitely many digits!  Where'd you get $n$ ?

Comment: In your notation $3.14159...314159...$, what does the first '...' mean? The usual meaning of $...$ means 'and so on', but if your '...' means 'and so on', then the decimal expansion continues indefinitely, and hence cannot be followed by anything.

Comment: the definition of "normal" number refers to finite strings of digits.  Clearly, for instance, $\pi$ does not contain the string $111\cdots$

Comment: What do you think you do along the $\Rightarrow$?

Comment: The claim is that $\pi$ contains all **finite** strings of decimals.  That is different from including the infinite string that is $\pi$.  We do not know whether the claim is trrue.

Comment: If your claim was that $\pi$ has some digits and then it ends with a copy of the whole decimal expansion of $\pi$, then there is an even simpler absurd: the first $n$ digits of $\pi$ must actually be the period of $\pi$.

Comment: "..." doesnot mean infinity it can be seen because I opened unbrace "n terms"//

I just assumed that if it has pi in it then it must be rational but pi isnot so every number combianiton isnot involved in pi. //

Yes I know it seems like very ignorant, I think the known misconception is defined in different way

Comment: "We do not know whether π consists every real number in its decimals, or not."  Yes, we do.  We know it does not.  What we don't know is if $\pi$ contains ever *integer* in its decimals or not (although it probably does).

Comment: Alright, why every integer combination doesnot mean the real numbers because every real numbers can be written as sum of integers (infinitely many of course).

Comment: It *is* hypothetically possible that $\pi$ does start with $n$ digits and then repeats those exact same digits and then continues on.  But those $n$ digits are not $\pi$ but pit to the first n digits.  But the main reason $\pi$ can't contain $\pi$ within it, is that... that just doesnt make any sense.  $\pi$'s digits are infinite and to be "in" something means there is something *after* it.  Or it means it repeats itself at the end infinitely.

Comment: Actually that argument would be fine if $\pi$ were rational.  $\frac 17 = 0.14285714285714285714285714285714...$ "contains itself".  Hypothetically it's possible that if $\pi$ ends with the infinite digits of $e$ that $\pi$ contains $e$ (or vice versa) but that is almost certainly not the case.  The only irrational numbers $\pi$ can contain are the irrational numbers that are an infinite tail of $\pi$.  Which is to say "almost none of them".  Anyway, good job figuring out that something is hinky +1.

Comment: Can we exactly say that $\pi$ has no the $e$ tail? In addition, actually, we can observe as many as infinity number of irrational at the tail of $\pi$ why not there is a $e$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Note, that if we construct a number in a way you've mentioned, we will obtain a repeater fraction. The numbers, that can be represented as a repeter fraction are rationals, while $\pi$ is not.

$$x10^n = 10 \lfloor10^{n-1}x\rfloor+x$$

$$x= \frac{10 \lfloor10^{n-1}x\rfloor}{10^n-1}\in\mathbb{Q}$$

Thus we could say, that for every non-rational number $x$ (eg. $\pi$) there is no $n\in\mathbb{N}$ , such that $x$ satisfies the first equation.

Answer (score 0):

Your argument applies in greater generality. In fact, it is a proof that any real number with decimal expansion that eventually repeats is rational.

In your case, you assumed that $\pi$ had repeating decimal expansion, and then proved it was rational.